# If $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} g(x)$ both exist

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be functions and $a \in \mathbb{R}$ Both functions have domain and codomain $\mathbb{R}$. Is it true that if $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} g(x)$ both exist, then $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ exists? I don't know how to prove this right or wrong.

Comment: Exists... where? In $\mathbb{R}$ or for instance, $[-\infty,\infty]$?

Comment: Exists in $\mathbb{R}$. I edited the question to include this.

Comment: surely you need $\lim g(x) \neq 0$.

Comment: For the given information, no. For instance, take $f(x) = x^2$ and $g(x) = x^3$ as $x \to 0$.

Comment: Ah, but Caroline, if the limits of $f$ and $g$ are both zero then we might be able to recover an answer via L'Hopital's rule?

Comment: @bounceback of course. I guess I was a little too fast with that.

Answer (score 2):

[KM101](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/596598/km101)'s answer is basically it -- no, it's not true in general.

One way to prove it false is to simply provide a counter-example. Here's one which avoids the issue [bounceback](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/480329/bounceback) brought up of indeterminate forms:
$$
f(x) = 1 \space ; \space g(x) = x \space ; \space a = 0
$$

Note that $$\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 0}( 1 )= 1$$ and that $$\lim_{x\to a} g(x) = \lim_{x \to 0}( x )= 0$$

So both limits exist at $a = 0$. But as for their quotient,
$$\lim_{x\to a} f(x)/g(x) = \lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{1}{x},$$

which does not exist -- it approaches $-\infty$ from the left and $\infty$ from the right.